# rdlc report in vs2010, how do i repeat column header on every page?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rdlc, ssrs-2008

How do I repeat column header (captions) in RDLC reports?

It says here http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/735D1EE7-3C89-46D8-A346-504DB10F33E1.aspx#TableNoGroups:

> To repeat or freeze column headings for the tablix member, select the static row that is labeled (Static). The properties pane displays the properties for the selected tablix member. By setting properties for this tablix member, you can control how the first row repeats or stays in view.

However I've tried turning "RepeatOnNewPage" and "FixedData" on and off, and nothing happened (the column header still showed up only in first page).
I'm using VS2010, thanks!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I just had this same problem and found that you likely need to go a bit further from the standard properties (right-side dialog) into the Advance properties.

After selecting your Tablix, there should be a frame at the bottom showing Row Groups and Column Groups, with an arrow at the far right.  Click the arrow and select advanced mode.

Now, the RowGroups section should show (Static) and (Details1), maybe more depending upon your Tablix.  Select the static row and in the right-side properties window, there will be an option to RepeatOnNewPage.

After I did this, my column headers displayed as I expected.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've changed property "RepeatOnNewPage" of the (Static) row group, but the row header just doesn't show up in page 2, page 3.. only shows on page 1. Anything else I might missed?

Comment: owww...thankssss....it solved my problem after 3 days of effort! how did you find it!!? I think microsoft makes it so complex to say YES! I am complex!...anyway thanks... :-)

Comment: This mostly worked for me. I also had to set the KeepWithGroup to After and FixedData to true. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/10/13/repeat-header-and-visible-fixed-header-table.aspx for details.

Comment: this answer was relevant a year ago and relevant today +1

Comment: Awesome. Why couldn't it have been so much easier? Not that it was hard to do, but hard to find. Best part is, this also works on subreports and for some reason I recall reading that you can't get rowheaders to repeat on new pages in subreports.

Comment: On the same advanced properties window also set 
"KeepTogether = true" and "KeepWithGroup = After"

Comment: This worked for me but only after setting every single one for that row.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this nagging issue in my bug list for months!  I want to make it clear that KDrewiske gave me the solution so don't vote for me, but I can't seem to reply to deerchao's followup question.  (Sorry, I'm new to the site)

In addition to KDrewiske's solution, I had to select the second row ('Details1' from the previous example) and turn KeepTogether to false.

I now get column headers on every page and can remove a pesky bug from my list!

Regards,
bizzarry

Comment: Thanks. Still not working for me, Strangely. Here'are my property values: (Static): RepeatOnNewPage = True, Hidden = False; (Details): Hidden = False; all other properties are set to their default values (not shown as bold in property grid). And my VS version is: 10.0.30319.341. How about yours?

Comment: I'm also using VS 2010.  Specifically, 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel.  All of my bold properties for the first Static row are: KeepTogether:True, KeepWithGroup:After, RepeatOnNewPage:True, Hidden:False.  Settings for the second row (Details) are: Hidden:False.  I also have a third row but I'm pretty sure that's just because of my particular table.  It is indented under (Details) and the only bold property is: Hidden:false.

Comment: Thanks very much! it's working now. Seems I've missed the "KeepWithGroup" property.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer in the second set of instrucions on the page represented by the url below.  I found this page by following a link on the page that deerchao provided a link to.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/cc627566.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If u want to display Tablix header more than 1 page(s) in Report the followings things to be Observed [(example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVmxG.png)

1. Just click once your table
2. After select your table you will see the Row Groups and Column Groups Portion
3. On the End of Right Side of Column Groups part you will see the down Arrow mark, just click arrow mark and select "Advanced Mode".
4. In Row Groups Part:
     *Static and other one is Details will be there
     *click once again static in Row Groups and press `F4` and you will see the property window and make Change to "True" for "RepeatOnNewPage" Property.