# Visual Studio 2010 - Repeating same report page x times based on parameter value

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

Currently a report page is setup to output desired content.

I have the footer stating which page from the total number of pages using built in global fields

> ="Page: " & Globals!PageNumber & " of " & Globals!TotalPages

I am looking to repeat/duplicate the entire report on page 2,3,..,x.
This will be decided by a parameter value on the report, which a user will choose loading the report.

Searching for similar scenarios, I have chosen to repeat row headers/column headers, but I'm unsure how to force the report to repeat on a new page. Most of the examples show extended datasets spanning further pages after page breaks.

--Only allowed to post 2 links, will try to post as comments of threads I've used to try and reach a solution for my self.

Below are a few screenshots of my report/design.

[Design of my report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQqXy.png)

[Each Static row item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aKPQ.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457371/rdlc-report-in-vs2010-how-do-i-repeat-column-header-on-every-page

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207045(v=sql.105).aspx